# GermaNLTK: not finding files [python]

Tags: semantics, computational-linguistics, german, software, nltk

Following the instructions of [GermaNLTK](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rdn0hOnJNcOBWEZgipdDfSyjJdnv_sinuAUSDSpiQns/edit?hl=en#heading=h.gw1o0ekhnwty) I tried to install the german NLTK in Python. (I want to use the synsets for semantic-taging.)
But I couldn't find the files *germanet.py* and *GermanetDBBuilder.py* to download as the Introduction indicates in step 6 of the manual-section.

Thanks in advance! dia

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/wroberts/pygermanet? It looks like pygermanet used to be connected to NLTK, but is now a separate project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with GermaNet is that it is not an open ressource. You have to licence it (free of cost for noncommetcial academic research, but you need to sign a licence agreement) from Eberhard Karls University Tübingen. Licensing details can be found on the [GermaNet home page](http://www.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/GermaNet/)

Alternatives to GermaNet can be found in the [Open multilingual wordnet](http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/) or within [babelnet](http://babelnet.org/download)